# SQL superset of specified list

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I've got a straightforward table structure, but having difficulty figuring out the appropriate SQL query.

Table Structure:

```
Recipe        { id (pk), name, description, ... }
Ingredient    { recipe_id (fk), ingredient }
```

I'm trying to figure out the SQL to say.. "Given a list of ingredients, return the Recipes that have at least all of the specified ingredients"

(Another way to say it: the specified ingredients are a superset of the matching Recipe's ingredients)

EDIT: Is it possible to do `SELECT r.* FROM Recipe r` rather than from the Ingredient table?

Comment: how would you pass the list of ingredients to the query?

Comment: `WHERE ingredient IN ('Flour', 'Sugar')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with `group by` and aggregation.  One method is:

```
select i.recipe_id
from ingredients i
where i.ingredient in (<ingredient 1>, <ingredient 2>, . . .)
group by i.recipe_id
having count(distinct i.ingredient) = <number of ingredients you are looking for>;
```

Comment: Is it possible to do `SELECT r FROM Recipe r`?

Comment: Not in MySQL.  That is not valid syntax (`r.*` would be valid, assuming `r` is not a column in `Recipe`).

Comment: Thanks - To clarify, I'm asking if it's possible to do a select FROM Recipe table, rather than select FROM Ingredient table.

Comment: @monkey-wrench . . . You can use `IN`, `EXISTS`, or `JOIN` with the query in this answer (or something similar).  The recipe table doesn't have the information about ingredients, so it cannot answer your question.